# Does Ruby have a SlowEquals Function?

Tags: ruby

In a password hashing scheme, when comparing two password hashes, I know that I should use a slow equals function, one that will take the same amount of time regardless of the parameters.

I learned the importance of slow equals in "[Why is the SlowEquals function important to compare hashed passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100985/why-is-the-slowequals-function-important-to-compare-hashed-passwords)".

Does such a function exist in Ruby? If not, what gems can I use?

Comment: Comparing two hashes? Wouldn't they be strings?

Comment: Interesting. With a "proper" hash function, why is there any useful information to be derived from how long comparing two hashes takes? I understand you can run timing attacks against comparing passwords directly (if it errors out later, the first N characters passed muster), but does that also work for supposedly secure hashes?

Comment: For any questions about slow equals, have a look at the linked question.

Comment: Following that link until http://security.stackexchange.com/a/46215 there is a statement that there is nothing to be gained from timing attacks against password hash comparisons (so that using normal string or array compare is no problem).

Comment: Going back to the original article all of those threads refer to, there is a timing attack mentioned in case you use an unsalted hash (or a hash where the attacker already knows the salt for some reason, which seems like a weird scenario). Don't do that...

Comment: @Thilo in the end, the answerer still says "Having that said, using constant time comparison is a good practice as part of a defence-in-depth policy."

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it." So, what have you done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is constant-time string comparison library in Ruby, see [fast_secure_compare](https://github.com/daxtens/fast_secure_compare). But you shouldn't use it against two password hashes.

Consider such situation that when Bob tries to brute force Alice's password, what would happen?

1. Bob tries a password
2. The server hashes Bob's try
3. The server compares Bob's hash with Alice's hash

Since the two hashes tend to be very different even the two original passwords are similar, comparison using `==` will always fail at the very beginning.

On the other hand, if the two hashes only have one different character at the end, it doesn't reflect the similarity of the two original passwords, and Bob still knows nothing about Alice's password.

Comment: "Shouldn't use it" is a bit strong. I agree that you don't have to use it (see the discussion in the comments on the question, including the link to an article where someone makes a case for using it), but there is no harm if you do (except minimal CPU time waste, most likely less than computing the hash needed it the first place).